# How do I fix an SDL Mixer "Unsupported block alignment" error?

Tags: audio, wav, sdl-2, playback, sdl-mixer

I'm using SDL2 and the SDL mixer library to attempt to play a WAV file. After calling the [`Mix_LoadWAV_RW`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_20.html#SEC20) function, I get the following error string: `"Unsupported block alignment"` In case it matters, I'll note that I got the `*SDL_RWops` by calling `SDL_RWFromMem` on a WAV file I have embedded into my source code as an array of bytes. That is, the first several bytes are the WAV header containing the text "RIFF: and "WAVE".

I'm guessing this means I need to re-encode my WAV file to a sub-format with a supported block alignment, but that is mostly a guess. Given I go with that guess, it seems like I would need to know what block alignments are supported.  I'm unable to find any relevant info in the [docs](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC_Top) about which alignments are supported.

I've also tried searching this [github mirror of the source code for SDL mixer](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL_mixer) for ["Unsupported block alignment"](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL_mixer/search?q=%22Unsupported+block+alignment%22&unscoped_q=%22Unsupported+block+alignment%22) but I didn't get any results. Does that mean that the error is coming from some dependency of SDL Mixer or something?

Does anyone know more about this error, where I can find more information on this error, or even a reasonable guess as to how I should change my WAV file to work here?

Comment: WAV decoding done by SDL itself, e.g. https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/bc59d0d4a2c814900a506d097a381077b9310509/src/audio/SDL_wave.c#L1729 . Probably easiest way to find source of your problem is building debug SDL, setting breakpoint in that function and inspecing decoded file header.

Comment: Aha! I hadn’t realized that plain SDL was doing the WAV decoding. And indeed, in that file there are [two](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/bc59d0d4a2c814900a506d097a381077b9310509/src/audio/SDL_wave.c#L1338) [different](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/bc59d0d4a2c814900a506d097a381077b9310509/src/audio/SDL_wave.c#L1152) places where the exact error message I am seeing was set. I think I have enough info to fix this myself now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I ended up just re-encoding the WAV file with default settings in Audacity, and it seems to have worked after that.